# jQuery Sortable validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, validation

I'm new to javascript & jquery but I'm attempting to get my head around how I would implement a validation form where when the user places/drags the images in the correct order the form can then be submitted. I have the images dragging in different orders and an alert box outputting the order in an array but how would I go about setting a value for the user to order the array of images in? I have the latest version of jQuery linked to the page and jQuery UI.

I'm trying to implement an if else statement in the code. I'm just not sure where I'm going wrong.
Heres what I got so far..

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  $(function() {
    //$('#submit').on('click', function() {
    //var valid = true,
    //message = '';

    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
      placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
      cursor: 'crosshair',
      update: function(event, ui) {
        var order = $("#sortable").sortable("toArray");
        $('#image_order').val(order.join(","));
        alert($('#image_order').val());
      }
    });
    
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();

    //if('#image_order').val { != [4,3,2,1];
    //valid = false; }
    //else {
    //window.location.href = "http://google.com"
    //}
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" id="image_order" name="image_order" value="" />

  <ul id="sortable" style="width: 524px;">
    <li id="1" class="ui-state-default"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x90/ff0000/000000.png&text=1" /></li>
    <li id="2" class="ui-state-default"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x90/ffff00/000000.png&text=2" /></li>
    <li id="3" class="ui-state-default"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x90/00ff00/000000.png&text=3" /></li>
    <li id="4" class="ui-state-default"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x90/00ffff/000000.png&text=4" /></li>  
  </ul>

  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  <input name="Submit" value="RE-ORDER" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I added placeholder images for you. jQUery UI is also enabled.

Comment: jQuery* UI is also enabled. Did you include the scripts in your local file?

Comment: Thanks :) do you know hoe I would implement this to require a certain pattern for the array? Like if the user had to order them in a certain way in order to proceed on a form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $(function() {


    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
      placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
      cursor: 'crosshair',
      update: function(event, ui) {
        var order = $("#sortable").sortable("toArray");
        order = JSON.stringify(order);
        correct = JSON.stringify(["4","3","2","1"]);
        if (order==correct){
            //ENABLE WHATEVER HERE
        }
      }
    });

    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();

  });
});
```

Comment: No need to use the JSON parser, just `function isEqual(arr1,arr2){return arr1.join('').localeCompare(arr2.join(''))==0;}`

Comment: @IsaacRay: Interesting... `JSON.stringify()` is about ***~4%*** faster in Google Chrome than `Array.join()` but in Mozilla Firefox, `Array.join()` is ***~84%*** faster than `JSON.stringify()`. [**See: Performance test *(results at bottom of page)***](http://jsperf.com/array-equals-compare).

Comment: @IsaacRay guys can I ask another possibly stupid question? Sorry I'm just confused about one thing. I want to redirect the user once the validated json array has passed as correct.. no problem with that, but if I allow the user to input data in required text fields. Then I get an error. Both content seems to be interfering. The user can only submit the form when the content is filled in. But when I hit submit the code says it requires the image_order too.

Comment: Validate both at the same time. Use a composite validation.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, that IS interesting. I suggested the stringify approach mostly because it seemed more readable than an additional function or one of the other approaches that would allow direct array comparison, but very curious that Chrome and Mozilla work so drastically different in terms of performance on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `validate()` function that checks when you sort and when you submit the form.

```
<input name="Submit" value="RE-ORDER" type="submit" onclick="return validate();"/>
```

You can return a boolean for wheter the form is valid or not to stop the `onClick` function from propagating.

Just go through the fields and make sure the order is correct before allowing the user to proceed.

```js
var expectedOrder = ["4", "3", "2", "1"];
var currentOrder = [];

window.validate = function() {
  if ($('#username').val().trim() === '') {
    return false;
  }
  if (!isEqual(currentOrder, expectedOrder)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#sortable').sortable({
    placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
    cursor: 'crosshair',
    update: function (event, ui) {
      currentOrder = $("#sortable").sortable("toArray");
      if (validate()) {
        alert('Navigating to http://www.google.com...');
      }
      $('#sortable').disableSelection();
    }
  });
});

function isEqual(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.join('').localeCompare(arr2.join('')) === 0;
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 8px;
}
.req {
  color: #FF0000;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<form action="" method="post">
  <label>Username:<span class="req" title="Field Required">*</span></label> 
  <input id="username" name="username" type="text" />
  <br />
  <input type="hidden" id="image_order" name="image_order" value="" />
  <ul id="sortable" style="width: 524px;">
    <li id="1" class="ui-state-default">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x90/ff0000/000000.png&text=1" />
    </li>
    <li id="2" class="ui-state-default">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x90/ffff00/000000.png&text=2" />
    </li>
    <li id="3" class="ui-state-default">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x90/00ff00/000000.png&text=3" />
    </li>
    <li id="4" class="ui-state-default">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x90/00ffff/000000.png&text=4" />
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  <input name="Submit" value="RE-ORDER" type="submit" onclick="return validate();"/>
</form>
```